# How do I make a circle move on events?

Tags: javafx-2

I'm pretty new to javafx so I'm trying to learn here so please be reasonable and don't dis away my question, I really appreciate any help at all, thanks!

I would like to know how I could move an object, let's say this circle on different events, like keypress or mouseclick, mousemove, whatever.

```
Circle circle = new Circle();
circle.setCenterX(100.0f);
circle.setCenterY(100.0f);
circle.setRadius(50.0f);
```

Do I need to use that KeyFrame thing I saw on the javafx site tutorial, or how does this work?

I would not have asked this here if I weren't feeling so lost, honestly. 
So to make this clear: What is the code for moving objects that I created, by using events?

EDIT:  By moving it I mean, press up key and it moves up by a few pixels, transform it maybe, with another key, or click somewhere on the scene and make it move there instantly or travel there with a certain speed. I don't have to redraw it like you need to with html5 canvas, I hope, right?

Comment: how exactly do you want to move it?

Comment: good point, I'll update my question, thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I don't have to redraw it like you need to with html5 canvas, I hope, right?

Not if you are using a standard [JavaFX scene graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/scenegraph/jfxpub-scenegraph.htm) as opposed to a [JavaFX canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm).

> I would like to know how I could move an object, let's say this circle on different events, like keypress or mouseclick, mousemove, whatever

There are three ways to move a [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html):

1. You can adjust the shape's geometry (e.g. the [centerX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html#centerXProperty)/centerY properties of a circle).
2. You can adjust the shape's layout (e.g. it's [layoutX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty)/layoutY properties).
3. You can adjust the shape's translation (e.g. it's [translateX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty%28%29)/translateY properties).

You can think of the layout as the home position for the object; i.e. where it should normally be in the context of it's parent group.  You can think of it's translation transform as a temporary position for an object (often used when the object is being animated).

If you are using a layout pane such as a [VBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) or [TilePane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html), then the layout pane will handle setting the layout co-ordinates of the child node for you.  If you are using a simple [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) or a plain [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) or [Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html), then you are responsible for setting the correct layout values for the child nodes.

To listen for events, set [event handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm) on [Nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) or [Scenes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html).

Here is a [small sample app](https://gist.github.com/4569878) which demonstrates the above.  It places the object to be moved inside a `Group` and modifies the position of the object within a `Group` in response to various events.

[image: movementevents]

Comment: wow, brilliant explanation, with examples and everything, thank you so much!

Comment: What a perfect answer