# Move text left and right in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm supposed to make a program where if you click on the top different buttons the background color changes, and if if you click on the bottom left and right button, it moves the text. I already got the former part working, but I can't seem to get the text to move left and right when I click on their buttons.

How do I fix this?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import static java.awt.FlowLayout.LEFT;
import static javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.LEFT;
import static javax.swing.JSplitPane.LEFT;
import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT;
import static java.awt.Event.LEFT;
import static java.awt.Label.LEFT;
import static javafx.geometry.HPos.LEFT;
import static javafx.geometry.HorizontalDirection.LEFT;
import static javafx.geometry.Side.LEFT;
import static javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData.LEFT;
import static javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay.LEFT;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.LEFT;
import static javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment.LEFT;
import static com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.Direction.LEFT;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;     
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class Unit08_Prog1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //add Radio Button (colors)
    ButtonGroup colors = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton red = new JRadioButton("Red");
    JRadioButton yellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
        JRadioButton white = new JRadioButton("White");
    JRadioButton orange = new JRadioButton("Orange");
    JRadioButton green = new JRadioButton("Green");
    //add text area
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Welcome to Java" , 5 , 30);
    //add buttons
    JButton  btLeft = new JButton("Left");
    JButton btRight = new JButton("Right");
    KeyListener keyListener;

    /**
     * @Description: populate frame with 3 panels
     * 
     *               1st changes colors 2nd edits text 3rd contains two buttons:
     *               Clear and Quit which have Mnemonics of "C" and "Q"
     */
    public Unit08_Prog1() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //populate ButtonGroup
        colors.add(red);
        colors.add(yellow);
        colors.add(white);
        colors.add(orange);
        colors.add(green);
        // create panel 1 (panel changes text area's color)
        JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
        colorPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        colorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Select Message Background"));
        colorPanel.add(red);
        colorPanel.add(yellow);
        colorPanel.add(white);
        colorPanel.add(orange);
        colorPanel.add(green);

        //Create panel 2 (add text area to frame)
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textPanel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //create panel 3 (add buttons to frame)
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(btLeft);
        btnPanel.add(btRight);
        //add panels
        add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //add listeners
        red.addActionListener(this);
        yellow.addActionListener(this);
        orange.addActionListener(this);
        white.addActionListener(this);
        green.addActionListener(this);

        btLeft.addActionListener(this);
        btRight.addActionListener(this);
        btLeft.setMnemonic('c');
        btRight.setMnemonic('q');
//      addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);



    }
    /** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
//    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
//      int key = e.getKeyCode();
//      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C){
//          textArea.setText("Welcome to Java");
//      }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
//          System.exit(0);
//      }
//    }
//     
//    /** Handle the key pressed event from the text field. */
//    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
//      int key = e.getKeyCode();
//      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C){
//          textArea.setText("Welcome to Java");
//      }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
//          System.exit(0);
//      }
//    }
//     
//    /** Handle the key released event from the text field. */

    //    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    //      int key = e.getKeyCode();

//      
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create frame
        Unit08_Prog1 frame = new Unit08_Prog1();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,200));
        frame.setTitle("Unit08_Prog1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getSource() == red){
            textArea.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }else if(arg0.getSource() == yellow){
            textArea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }else if(arg0.getSource() == orange){
            textArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }else if(arg0.getSource() == white){
            textArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }else if(arg0.getSource() == green){
            textArea.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm

Comment: You can use the same ideas on a `Label`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399690/how-do-i-make-a-circle-move-on-events

Comment: Also, to save you a headache down the road, remove the `awt` imports and replace them with `JavaFX` imports.

Comment: Actually, I can't tell if you are creating a `JavaFX` app or `Swing` app.

Comment: It's a javaFX app

Comment: You seem to be using a lot of `Swing` components. So take my advice above. That includes replacing all of the `Swing` imports too.

Comment: In fact you don't seem to be using javafx classes at all. You just seem to add static imports to every single `LEFT` member in the java api...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a JavaFX application. There is not a single element in your code that would use FX platform.

Second, I think you should really think about your code. Implementing `ActionListener` and handling different types of actions in one place isn't a good idea in my opinion.

So, I found out that aligning text using `JTextArea` is kind of problematic, because, while it does work, it starts to work when you change text inside the area, which is weird.

Can you use `JTextField` instead? If you can, here would be the solution for your specific case:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class Unit08_Prog1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //add Radio Button (colors)
    ButtonGroup colors = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton red = new JRadioButton("Red");
    JRadioButton yellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
    JRadioButton white = new JRadioButton("White");
    JRadioButton orange = new JRadioButton("Orange");
    JRadioButton green = new JRadioButton("Green");
    //add text area
    JTextField textArea = new JTextField("Welcome to Java");
    JScrollPane scroll;
    //add buttons
    JButton btLeft = new JButton("Left");
    JButton btRight = new JButton("Right");
    KeyListener keyListener;

    /**
     * @Description: populate frame with 3 panels
     * <p>
     * 1st changes colors 2nd edits text 3rd contains two buttons:
     * Clear and Quit which have Mnemonics of "C" and "Q"
     */
    public Test() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //populate ButtonGroup
        colors.add(red);
        colors.add(yellow);
        colors.add(white);
        colors.add(orange);
        colors.add(green);
        // create panel 1 (panel changes text area's color)
        JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
        colorPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        colorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Select Message Background"));
        colorPanel.add(red);
        colorPanel.add(yellow);
        colorPanel.add(white);
        colorPanel.add(orange);
        colorPanel.add(green);

        //Create panel 2 (add text area to frame)
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textPanel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //create panel 3 (add buttons to frame)
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(btLeft);
        btnPanel.add(btRight);
        //add panels
        add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //add listeners
        red.addActionListener(this);
        yellow.addActionListener(this);
        orange.addActionListener(this);
        white.addActionListener(this);
        green.addActionListener(this);

        btLeft.addActionListener(this);
        btRight.addActionListener(this);
        btLeft.setMnemonic('c');
        btRight.setMnemonic('q');
//      addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);


    }

    /**
     * Handle the key typed event from the text field.
     */
//    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
//      int key = e.getKeyCode();
//      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C){
//          textArea.setText("Welcome to Java");
//      }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
//          System.exit(0);
//      }
//    }
//     
//    /** Handle the key pressed event from the text field. */
//    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
//      int key = e.getKeyCode();
//      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C){
//          textArea.setText("Welcome to Java");
//      }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
//          System.exit(0);
//      }
//    }
//     
//    /** Handle the key released event from the text field. */

    //    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    //      int key = e.getKeyCode();

//      
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getSource() == red) {
            textArea.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if (arg0.getSource() == yellow) {
            textArea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (arg0.getSource() == orange) {
            textArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        } else if (arg0.getSource() == white) {
            textArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        } else if (arg0.getSource() == green) {
            textArea.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if ("Left".equals(arg0.getActionCommand())) {
            textArea.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        } else if ("Right".equals(arg0.getActionCommand())) {
            textArea.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, I didn't make any changes to your code, but I think you should.